# The derivative , the tangent line and inertial motion in a counterfactual scenario

Tags: calculus

This question is asked at the most basic level, as an attempt to understand better the concept of the derivative and the interest of the concept.

Suppose I have a curve representing a function f ( with say X axis representing distance across, and Y axis representing height).  Suppose there is a mobile object ( for example a plane, a skateborder...) moving on the curve and that this mobile object can be represented by a point ( also moving on the curve). Suppose P is a point on the curve.

What I am asking myself is the folllowing. Is it right to say that the question

(1) " what is the derivative of f at point P?"

is equivalent to the question

(2) " what would be the slope of the line the object **would** follow **if it suddenly left the curve and continued it's way with a pure inertial motion** ( without gravity or any force acting on it)"?

More generally : is it relevant to relate the "tangent line problem" to inertia?

Remark. I have found a counter example to the rephrasing I proposed.

Suppose the curve is the graph of the function defined by f(x) = |x|. If the object leaves the curve at point (0,0) , the slope of the rectilinear trajectory the object would follow would not be the derivative of f for x=0.

I think I should add as proviso to my rephrasing : the derivative at point x is the slope of the line the object would follow by inertia PROVIDED , **in case the object would move backwards in the direction of the curve , it would continue its path on the curve, and not turn back**.  An object leaving f(x)= |x| at (0,0) and then moving backwards would not continue its path on the curve ( from x=0 to infinity); it would go back from x=0 to minus infinity.

In brief, **my scenario does not take into account the two-sided-limit condition for the existence of the derivative at a point.**

Comment: Yes you may say that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right, if you cancel all forces, the moving body will continue it's way in a straight line, following the tangent at the trajectory.

For a curve of equation $y=f(x)$, the derivative $f'(x)$ is the slope of the tangent.

---

Technically, the law of dynamics says $\vec F=m\vec a$, where $\vec a$ is the acceleration, i.e. the derivative of the speed on time. So when $\vec F=0$, the speed is constant and the displacement

$$\vec p=\vec vt+\vec p_0.$$

Expanding the components,

$$\begin{cases}x=v_xt+x_0,\\y=v_yt+y_0\end{cases}.$$

Then if you eliminate time,

$$y=\frac{v_y}{v_x}(x-x_0)+y_0.$$

You will sooner or later learn that

$$\frac{v_y}{v_x}=\frac{\dfrac{dy}{dt}}{\dfrac{dx}{dt}}=\frac{dy}{dx}=f'(x).$$

Comment: Merci pour cette réponse détaillée. C'est un peu technique pour moi j'avoue , mais j'y reviendrai quand j'aurai fait quelques progrès...

Comment: @EleonoreSaintJames: it's because time enters into play.